# Image inside ImageButton not scaling to fill button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

My layout includes this ImageButton as shown:

[image: You can see in this picture]

But as you can see, the image is not taking the full size of the ImageButton.

This is the layout file where the ImageButton is defined:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/dashboard_profile"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

As you can see, I already added `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, but it's not working.

I also tried to change the button size in Android Studio's design mode, but it's not letting me change.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: There might be some padding in the image itself which you are trying to set as the source for this `ImageButton`

Comment: I agree with @HarshitDwivedi. Please check you image first. Check if has some extra padding inside it. And set  the image as `android:src`.

Comment: How am I suppose to remove the padding on the image?

Comment: Use any image editor like GIMP or Photoshop to do that. @AlexandreCristo

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, on my image editor the image appears the right way. You can see in [here](http://imgur.com/a/Mne8P).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Imageview, Imagebutton has a padding around the image area. This is intentional. This is because of the default button style. You can do one of the following:

- Use a borderless button style as your background.
  `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`
- Set your background as null.
  `android:background="@null"`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, but how am I suppose to scale the button?

Comment: What do you mean by scaling?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/dashboard_profile"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:src="@mipmap/dashboard_profile"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="71dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: No. I suggest **android:src**