# Why is the same layout_weight leading to different widths for Android ImageButton and Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton, android-layout-weight

I'm getting some weird behavior in my LinearLayout when I try to set regular Buttons and an ImageButton to the same `layout_weight`. The image button's `android:src` resource is extrememly small and fits well inside the ImageButton without any problems. Even though their widths should be identical, for some reason the ImageButton's width is about 2/3rds the size of the rest of the normal buttons. If I multiply the ImageButton's `layout_weight` by 10, its much closer to the right size, but why isn't this working?

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/clear"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/left_paren"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/left_paren"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/right_paren"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/right_paren"/>
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/backspace"
            android:src="@drawable/backspace"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think always use. layout_width="0dp".instead of your android:layout_width="wrap_content".Whenever we use layout_weight.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41451132/2219600

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for all buttons that should be the same width. (More precisely, you need to set the same `layout_width` for all those buttons and `0dp` is the conventional width to use. When using equal weights, as long as there's still extra space to distribute, the actual width you use isn't relevant to the result.) The `layout_weight` only determines how the *remaining* space is allocated after the buttons take up their assigned widths. So if they start out unequal (which they will with widths of `wrap_content`), they remain different after their weights are taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set equal `android:layout_weight` to all views and set the `android:layout_width` to `0dp` to achieve a equal portion of the width to all views.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left_paren"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/left_paren" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right_paren"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/right_paren" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backspace"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/backspace"
            android:src="@drawable/plus" />
    </LinearLayout>
```